# Embedd pig in python . AttributeError: SimplePigStats object has no attribute 'isSuccessfull'

Tags: python, hadoop, embed, apache-pig

Came across a python error while running pig embedded in Python script. Solved the problem but want to know if anyone else came across this error.

Scenario: a) Python script with pig goes like this.

```
pigRun = Pig.compileFromFile(self.settingsReader.getScriptsDir() + "/" + script.name)
params = { 'datefrom': '2012-08-04 00:00:00', 'dateto': '2012-12-05 00:00:00', 
       'parallelism':self.settingsReader.getParallelism(), 
       'input' : script.input, 'output':script.output}
        bound = pigRun.bind(params)
        stats=bound.runSingle()
        if not stats.isSuccessfull():
          raise 'failed'
```

b) Pig version is 0.10. Python 2.7, Jython 2.5
Getting error on the lines

```
if not stats.isSuccessfull():
          raise 'failed'
```

c) Error is as follows
AttributeError: 'org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats' object has no attribute 'isSuccessfull'

After looking at the source for Apache PIG 0.10, SimplePigStats seems to have isSuccessfull() implemented in it. But the runtime error says it is not.

Temporary Solution: Changed the failure check code as follows

```
bound = pigRun.bind(params)
stats= bound.runSingle()
     if stats.getReturnCode() != 0:
        raise 'failed'
```

This seems to work fine.

Comment: Successful is spelled "successful" (one L).  Is that your problem?

Comment: Great catch. Thank you so much. I have not tried but definitely it seem to be. One question though, i am on eclipse with PyDev. How come it did not tell me that this is not a valid identifier/function in that class (i am coding blind as if on a note pad). Also, when I add jython jar to eclipse it hangs. The Stats class is actually a pig jar content which I added to my eclipse project as external jar/dependency. Any leads?

Comment: I don't really know anything about pig, I just noticed what seemed to be a typo in your code.  Those other things sound like different questions and you should make a new stackoverflow post for them.